# How do I update wordpress elementor page programmatically

Tags: elementor, custom-wordpress-pages, update-post-meta

I`m making new plugin for auto publishing pages which build with elementor page builder. I made new template with specific words such as "{key}" or "{city}" and then plugin is using that template  page to publish new pages. plugin has different word examples to exchange with specific words and they will exchange after button click. To do this, I` m going to get data from post and then analysed structure and find specific word and replace them with news.
but nothing happened

it is my example data to exchange
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhUl1.png)
to do this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt9uK.png)
I used  "post_content" function to get whole data and also used "get_post_meta" function.
but in that step, there is nothing printed.
and then replace FAQ data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UYTj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k9LA.png)

in this step, all contents replaced successfully.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbE6z.png)
and I think I have to change meta data.
but I can not do this.
How can I change my code ?

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)